# nvd3 format 2 lines separately on y axis

Tags: javascript, graph, d3.js, nvd3.js

I am plotting 2 lines on y-axis, is it possible to format these lines separately. 
Here is my data :

```
var dataMy = [
    {
        "key": "key1",
        "values": [
            [
                1697000000,
                (19024000000-mean1)/std1
            ],
            [
                1764000000,
                (19764000000-mean1)/std1
            ],
            [
                1829000000,
                (21496000000-mean1)/std1
            ]
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "key2",
        "values": [
            [
                1697000000,
                (13530000-mean2)/std2
            ],
            [
                1764000000,
                (41790000-mean2)/std2
            ],
            [
                1829000000,
                (29280000-mean2)/std2
            ]
        ]
    }
]
```

while showing the graph I want all values of key1 to be changed to :

```
  y(i) = y(i) * std1 + mean1;
```

and values of key2 as :

```
 y(i) = y(i) * std2 + mean2;
```

i can only pass one function to format y values, is there a way to know in formatter function that value i belongs to key1 or key 2 so that i can apply if else,

```
  formatter = function(i){
      if(i from key1)
         return i*std1 + mean1;
      else if(i from key2)
         return i*std2 + mean2;
  };

  chart.yAxis     //Chart y-axis settings
      .axisLabel('Voltage (v)')
      .tickFormat(formatter);
```

i values are all the y values shown on y-axis and points on graph, y-values of both lines are received in formatter function in alternate sequence. so if i apply reverse mapping alternately it works but when i un select a line from legend this function is called again and this time with only one line alternate values will be applied giving wrong results.

Comment: NVD3 doesn't support this out of the box, you would have to modify the source code.

Comment: we can create 2 arrays, `normalize1 = (arr1[i]-mean1)/std1` and `normalize2 = (arr2[i]-mean2)/std2` and in if condition i can check if  value i is in normalize1 then return  `i*std1 + mean1` else return `i*std2 + mean2`. problem with this i see is lot of extra looping, 2 loops to create arrays `normalize1` and `normalize2` and all if conditions will be checking if value i belong to `normalize1` or `normalize2` is extra over head. there is one more issue what if same value is present in 2 arrays `normalize1` and `normalize2`.